# How to cut data in even pieces in R?

Tags: r, cut, sampling

Here is the problem: I have a dataset, let's say:

```
a <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

I want to cut it into even pieces (e.g. 5 pieces ). The problem is I cannot use quantiles or cut because some values repeat, so you cannot set distinct breakpoints.

```
> quantile(a)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   0    0    1    1    1
```

(repeated breakpoints)

```
> cut(a, 5)
 [1] (-0.001,0.199] (-0.001,0.199] (-0.001,0.199] (-0.001,0.199] (0.801,1]     
 [6] (0.801,1]      (0.801,1]      (0.801,1]      (0.801,1]      (0.801,1]     
Levels: (-0.001,0.199] (0.199,0.4] (0.4,0.6] (0.6,0.801] (0.801,1]
```

(only two levels used)

I know I can produce a vector like this:

```
b <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
```

and use it for sampling. Or I can use for loop and count instances. But this needs loops and some clumsy coding. I am looking for a simple and efficient (R-style) function that does better than this.

(I can write it but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut`, but you have to use it on the numerical indices of the vector, i.e., `seq(a)`, not the vector itself.

Then you split the vector into pieces of equal length with `split`:

```
split(a, cut(seq(a), 5, labels = FALSE))
```

This returns a list of five short vectors.

Another way, without `cut`, is given by

```
split(a, rep(seq(5), each = length(a) / 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you are going to do next. I like dim:

```
dim(a) <- c(2, length(a) / 2)
```

And now a looks this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    1
```